# For each positive integer $n$, let $x_n=1/(n+1)+1/(n+2)+\cdots+1/(2n)$. Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For each positive integer $n$, let $x_n=1/(n+1)+1/(n+2)+\cdots+1/(2n)$. Prove that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges.

This is what I have so far..

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given to us. We must show that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $n\ge N \implies \left|\frac{1}{2n} - 1\right| < \epsilon$. Choose $N$ to be any positive integer which is larger than $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. (So $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.) Then $n\ge N \implies \left|\frac{1}{2n} - 1\right| = |\frac{1-2n}{2n}|$

Comment: I need to find a way such to show that |1/(2n) – 1| < ε

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac12=\frac n{2n}\le\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}\le\frac n{n+1}$$

$$X_{n+1}:=\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{n+3}+\ldots+\frac1{2(n+1)}\ge \frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}=:X_n$$

[Edit: Flipping the inequality the right way]

Comment: Can we find out to what number does the sequence converge? I know it is a monotonically increasing sequence bounded above by ln(2). Is ln(2) the supremum? Then, the limit would be ln(2). Is it?

Comment: The last inequality is the wrong way around. Note that the number of terms on both sides is not equal, which is clouded by the suggestive notation.

Comment: @DonAntonio Nice answer! But you haven't computed the limit. Btw, do you know how to calculate it without using Riemann sums ?

Comment: @Franklin This is very old...and the short answer is no: I don't know how to evaluate the limit without using Riemann sums. To prove the limit exists is done above in hints (bounded monotonic sequence), but the actual value of the limit...I personally can do it only with Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 15):

We write
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+k/n}\to\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}=\log 2$$

Comment: Big question, why is the integral up to 1?

Comment: @user63181 after putting x=k/n and dx/dk=1/n i.e dx=dk/n. but in the above integration you used simply dx. How ??

Answer (score 4):

The sequence is decreasing because $$x_{n+1}-x_n = \frac1{2n+2}+\frac1{2n+1} - \frac1{n+1} = \frac{1}{2(2n+1)(n+1)}\ge 0$$
and obviously, $x_n\le \frac{n}{n+1}\le 1$, so is convergent.
For proving that $x_n\to \log 2$ the better idea is bounding $x_n$ by definite integrals of the form $\int_a^b\frac1x\,dx$ (how?).

Comment: $-\frac{1}{n}$ is wrong, it should be $-\frac{1}{n+1}$, shouldn't it? But if so, you end up with $x_{n+1} \gt x_n$, right? Does it converge then?

Comment: @Flavius, corrected. Thanks.