# Find upper bound for sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$ Fn =  \frac{1}{n+1} +\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+n}$$

I need to show that 1 is an upper bound for this sequence.I tried to use induction but didn't manage to prove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prove$\frac 34\geq \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac {1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642895/how-do-i-prove-frac-34-geq-frac1n1-frac-1n2-frac1n3-cdots)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/525749/42969.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** observe that each term in the sum is bounded from above by $\frac{1}{n}$ and there are $n$ terms.